# Number of views a Report has had in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, popularity-trends

I'm attempting to find out how many views a report in a SharePoint 2013 library has had by using the 'Popularity Trends' button. Upon running the report no views are recorded - even though I've been viewing it. However, usage statistics are being collected at a site level.
Any suggestions / guidance welcomed.

Update: I've ensured the Usage and Health data collections have been configured, and waited 24 hours for any tweaks made to take affect, but still nothing.